# GTTS module error, ImportError: cannot import name gTTS

Tags: python, gtts

I am trying to make a Voice assistant in python using this code

```
import os
from gtts import gTTs
import time
import playsound
import speech_recognition as sr



def speak(text):
    tts = gTTS(text=text, lang="en")
    filename = "voice.mp3"
    tts.save(filename)
    playsound.playsound(filename)

def get_audio():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        audio = r.listen(source)
        said = ""

        try:
            said = r.recognize_google(audio)
            print(said)
        except Exception as e:
            print("Exception: " + str(e))

    return said


text = get_audio()

if "who are you" in text:
    speak(" I am Friday the virtual assistant")
```

And when i run it, it shows this error ImportError: cannot import name gTTS

Any help would be amazing :)

Edit:I have changed it to gTTS and still get ImportError: cannot import name gTTS

Answer (score 3):

Try replacing

```
from gtts import gTTs
```

with

```
from gtts import gTTS
```

(Note the capital `S`)

Comment: I have changed the code and still comes up with the error? Thanks for your help

Comment: Could you edit your question and copy/paste the actual error traceback into it? Because you shouldn't be getting that error any more.

Comment: We need the whole traceback: the piece of output that starts with `Traceback (most recent call last):` and ends with the error message.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Me/Desktop/Friday.py", line 5, in <module>
    from gtts import gTTS
 ImportError: cannot import name gTTS

Comment: Could you try this for me: `import gtts; print(dir(gtts))` and tell me what it outputs?

Comment: I get this Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Me/Desktop/Friday.py", line 5, in <module>
    import gtts; print(dir(gtts))
  File "/Users/Me/Desktop/gtts.py", line 5, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name gTTS

Comment: I am on mac os btw

Comment: Oh I see. You need to rename your `gtts.py`. It conflicts with the gtts library.

Comment: I have one more quick question do you know how i could search wolfram alpha with this?

Comment: I don't, that would be better asked in a separate question

Answer (score 1):

I also got this problem once because i named my python file as gtts.py
so i changed the name of the file to something else and  it stopped giving error.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to install the gtts module with this command by going to the terminal and type following line:

```
pip install gTTS
```

After you install this, import like this:

```
from gtts import gTTS
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error. Just make sure you are using the right python Interpreter.